# how to do postgis processing between two cursors in Python script?

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, postgresql, postgis, pydev

Please, can someone help me finish this script?

This program proposes to calculate the distance between two French cities that the user chooses (via the postal code aka insee).

I managed to connect to my database, to search separately for the two geometries (polygon centroid) but I can't redo postgis processing with these two cursors ...

I know the command postgis ST_Distance which would allow me to finish this program but I don't know how to use it.

Forgive my english, Regards

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="Python_test", 
                        user="*****",
                        host="localhost",
                        password="*****",
                        port="****") 

cur1 = conn.cursor()
cur2 =conn.cursor()
cur3=conn.cursor()
print("Ce module calcul la distance entre deux commune francaise a partir de leur code INSEE")
insee1=str(input("Entrez un premier code INSEE d'une commune francaise; a 5 chiffres :"))
insee2=str(input("Entrez un second code INSEE :"))


sql='''SELECT insee FROM base.commune_json'''
sql2='''SELECT st_transform(st_centroid(geom),2154) FROM base.commune_json'''

cur1.execute(sql, insee1)
cur1.execute(sql2,insee1)


cur2.execute(sql, insee2)
cur2.execute(sql2,insee2)



go = cur1.fetchone()
go2= cur2.fetchone()

print ('Nombre de km entre ville1 et ville 2 = '+str(go)+'---------------------' +str(go2))


conn.commit()
conn.close()




Résult:
>>> 'Nombre de km entre ville1 et ville 2 = Géometry of cur1 + '---------------------' + Géometry of cur2
```

Comment: Since the data is in the same DB, the simplest is to do everything in 1 query (i.e. search for 2 cities, extract the centroid, compute the distance).

Comment: Thanks you,
How to do the work with a single request when execute takes only one argument? 
I will try by creating views.

Comment: OK, this works just with %s %. Sorry. Topic close